# How to search if large text file contains words from sentence using python?

Tags: python, pandas, search, lemmatization

I have a text file containing words and their [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) - every line contains word form in the first column and word lemma in the second column.

I have a list of tweets (sentences) which I need to convert to word lemmas - each word needs to be converted to their lemma (the second column from a text file)

I tried opening and closing text file for each word but that takes too long (about 15 sec for every word to find their lemma in the text file). The function is below.

```
def returnLemma(str):
    str= word_tokenize(str)
    end_str = ""
    for word in str:
        infile = open('MorphDict.txt', 'r')
        for line in infile:
            line.strip()
            prva=line.split()[0] 
            druga=line.split()[1]
            if word==prva:
                end_str = end_str+" "+druga 
                break;
        infile.close()
    return end_str
```

Is it possible to search this text file (>100MB) more efficiently? Is it possible to use [pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this to solve it?

Comment: The answer is basically yes to both of your questions. But, you might consider refactoring this code so that the data from `MorphDict.txt` is read outside of the function (once) and passed as an argument. Side note: you currently use `str` as a name, which conflicts with a Python builtin

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible input data sets and your desired data set? PS what language are you asking about? Is it an english text?

Comment: Why would you use Pandas here?

Comment: @Javier Why wouldn't you? You could just concatenate the strings in a single command

Comment: @roganjosh well, at first glance, this seems to be a very simple function. Adding Pandas would make it more complex. I might be missing what you mean. A list could be used to hold the strings to concatenate and thus concatenate more efficiently than done in the post. If you post this code using Pandas, maybe it would clarify my misunderstanding.

Comment: I couldn't find a standard solution (like NLTK) for lemmatizing or stemming serbian language. So it might be tricky to build a generic solution... You may want to check [this](https://nikolamilosevic86.github.io/SerbianStemmer/). If i understood correctly your `MorphDict.txt` consists of two columns - this can be easily read in a Pandas DF for faster searching...

Comment: @MaxU I'm working with Serbian morphological dictionary. I want to normalize tweet like this:
"Suštinsko pitanje nije postavljeno: zašto predsednik odbora nije otvorio pretres a morao je"

to something like this:

"Suština pitanje nije postaviti: zašto predsednik odbor nije otvoriti pretres a morati je"

MorphDict.txt contains the following (word-word lemma)
Suštinsko Suština
pitanje pitanje 
nije nije
postavljeno postaviti
zašto zašto
predsednik predsednik 
odbora odbor
otvorio otvoriti
pretres pretres
morao morati
.....

Comment: So I don't see any problems in this case - you can create a corresponding dictionary from this file or read it into Pandas Series (with corresponding index) or a DataFrame. 200Mb text should easily fit into memory. Accessing dictionary values by keys is has `O(1)` complexity - si it will be pretty fast...

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, I already worked with stemmers, but now I want to use lemmas. I understand it is tricky so I can't use NLTK in my case. I'm not so good with panda package, I worked with data frame but I am not sure if that approach would be more time efficient. Actually, I am looking for the best data structure to transform my text file for faster search.

Comment: @Adela, you need to answer one important question - are you going to search the whole words in the file or their substrings as well? For example if you would search for `Suštin` in the file - do you expect to find something or not?

Comment: @MaxU I need to search whole words from MorphDict and find their lemmas.
For example Suštinsko need to be converted to Suština.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write that same function like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict


word_tokenize = lambda s: s.split()


def returnLemma(s, morph_lines):
    tokens = word_tokenize(s)
    token_positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
        token_positions[t].append(i)

    drugas = [None] * len(tokens)
    for line in morph_lines:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(maxsplit=3)
        prva = parts[0]
        try:
            positions = token_positions[prva]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            druga = parts[1]
            for i in positions:
                drugas[i] = druga

    return ' ' + ' '.join(
        druga if druga is not None else token
        for token, druga in zip(tokens, drugas)
    )


import unittest


class ReturnLemmaTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_when_nothing_matches_then_it_returns_a_single_space(self):
        result = returnLemma('hello world', ['line 1', 'line 2'])
        self.assertEqual(' hello world', result)

    def test_when_one_line_matches_then_it_returns_its_second_word(self):
        result = returnLemma('hello world line-b', ['line-a 1', 'line-b 2'])
        self.assertEqual(' hello world 2', result)

    def test_when_many_lines_match_then_it_returns_their_second_words_separated_by_a_space(self):
        result = returnLemma('hello b world b c', ['a 0', 'b 1', 'c 2'])
        self.assertEqual(' hello 1 world 1 2', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The second parameter to `returnLemma` can be an open file but it is easier to test with lists.

Comment: @roganjosh that's the best I can do without loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Apologies, I was distracted by newborn in the house! https://pastebin.com/KSRKWQXP would be _one_ pandas approach but I don't declare it the most efficient because I've not spent time properly thinking of the problem, but I did want to close a loose-end after commenting originally.

Comment: it's not quite a full approach, but it matches the OP check for equality

Comment: The entire file needs to be loaded into memory and parsed before beginning matching... AFAICS, for small amounts of data the speed benefit will be negligible, for large amounts it will not fit in memory. IMHO using Pandas for this will have a very narrow sweet spot. Thank you for showing what you meant.

Comment: Yes, we agree on the memory part. ">100MB" is... abstract. That gives a lot of leeway before it becomes an issue, but it's left open-ended

Comment: Yes, in this case it appears to be a tiny dataset so indexing into a dict or using might be best.

Comment: @Javier, your function doesn't return word in proper order. I forget to mention that the order of the words in the sentence is important. If I need to lemmatize sentence "walking is better than meeting" it needs to become something like "walk is good than meet" and not like "is walk  than good meet"

Comment: @Adela good point. I've updated to code to keep drugas in the same order as tokens.

Comment: @Javier, this code is ok, thanks. One more thing, if word lemma is not found than the first word needs to be returned (prva). I'm trying to edit the code so that case could be handled. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I've updated the code to do that but the code you posted on the question does not do that.

Comment: I haven't seen @Javier. Yes, both function does the same thing now.

Answer (score 1):

This is final and working code - with the minor change od @Javier's function. Thank everyone for the help, especially @Javier and @MaxU.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from collections import defaultdict

def vratiLemu(s, morph_lines):
    tokens = word_tokenize(s)
    token_positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
        token_positions[t].append(i)

    for line in morph_lines:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split()
        prva = parts[0]
        try:
            positions = token_positions[prva]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            druga = parts[1]
            for i in positions:
                tokens[i] = druga

    return ' ' + ' '.join(druga for druga in tokens if druga is not None)              

morphDict= open('SveSrpMDANSI.txt', 'r')
out=vratiLemu1("Suštinsko pitanje nije postavljeno: zašto predsednik odbora nije otvorio pretres a morao je",morphDict)
print out
```

Suštinsko pitanje jesam postavljen : zašto predsednik odbor jesam otvoriti pretres a morati jeste

Answer (score 0):

When you need to compare the elements of two lists and one is much smaller than the other, use the smallest in the inner loop. This will always be much more efficient.

Try not to do the same work twice. When you split the line, keep the parts so that you don't need to do it again.

`line.strip()` does no change `line` but instead generates a new line without blanks. Use `line = line.strip()`.

Instead of opening the file repeatedly, you can seek to the beginning.